# How to rewrite integration test for ModelAndView in Java

Tags: java, spring, junit, hamcrest

I had that controller

```
@GetMapping("/popular")
    public List<User> getPopularUsers() {
        return handler.getPopularUsers();
}
```

and integration test for it that worked correct:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/popular"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("[0].userId").value(372152))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("[1].userId").value(398729));
```

Now i changed my controller and it returns ModelAndView instead List:

```
@GetMapping("/popular")
    public ModelAndView getPopularUsers(Map<String, Object> map) {
        List<User> popularUsers = handler.getPopularUsers();
        map.put("users", popularUsers);
        return new ModelAndView("popular-users", map);
}
```

Can someone tell me how to rewrite test for new controller? I've found some examples using hamcrest library, but i really don't understand how to get some values from List

Answer (score 2):

For checking ModelAndView case, Spring MVC Test has several MVC matchers like ModelResultMatchers and ViewResultMatchers

If you want to check some value in your list you can use the method `public <T> ResultMatcher attribute(String name, Matcher<T> matcher)` from ModelResultMatchers.

The previous checks can be rewritten like this:

```java
.andExpect(model().attribute("users",hasItem(hasProperty("id", equalTo(372152)))));
.andExpect(model().attribute("users",hasItem(hasProperty("id", equalTo(398729)))));
```

Also, you can check the view, a check for this case can look like:

```java
.andExpect(view().name("popular-users"))
```

Full list of all MockMvcResultMatchers can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/MockMvcResultMatchers.html)

Full list of all possible methods for ModelResultMatchers can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ModelResultMatchers.html)

Full list of all possible methods for ViewResultMatchers can be found [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/result/ModelResultMatchers.html)